# Make android sql lite datatype always text

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create sqllite db for my Android application use

Is it bad habit to have all the data types as text? The reason is even though some data can be integer in nature (like number of items.. Etc) but many times I need to display the values as a string or get it as input from user. So I thought for easier manipulation I will just make the datatype in the db as text

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to understand here is [SQLite Storage Classes](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html). SQLite allows any data type to be stored in a table's columns, the actual data type defined by the table is just a hint to the database engine.

This means that even if you define a column as type `INTEGER`, you can still store text in it.

That being said, I haven't found a use case for storing arbitrary data types in a column, or a case for disregarding the defined data types. For readability purposes, it would probably be a good idea to type things properly and obey the defined types.

Comment: thanx for the comments. So if I am to do a select using conditions like > or <, then text/integer datatype wouldnt matter?

Comment: See section 3.0 from the docs I linked to, they spell out how comparison is implemented.